# Python, django: I think there is simple way to put all the phone numbers that Admin put on the html page, into the list_numbers'

Tags: python, django, twilio

I am not sure about the codes I wrote... and check if everything is okay.

1. Admin put all the numbers on the sms page (html). this page is hidden, this is only for admin
2. Admin hit the submit button
3. views.py perform the function of sending sms to those numbers

```
def sms(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        number1 = request.POST.get('number1')
        number2 = request.POST.get('number2')
        number3 = request.POST.get('number3')
        ...
        ...

        account_sid = 'AC@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
        auth_token = 'b25986445ce6ad186b1f7efac287fbe6'

        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        def sms_one(sendto):
            client.messages.create(body="Just reminder of your booking \
                                        \nSee you soon \                                        
                                        \n\nAny changes? please let us know\
                                        \nDo.Not.Reply.to.This.Number.\
                                        \nInstead, click => https://******.com/contact",
                                   from_='**********',
                                   to=sendto)

        list_numbers = [number1, number2, number3, ...............]

        def sms_all(listnumbers):
            for number in listnumbers:
                sms_one(number)

        sms_all(list_numbers)

        return render(
            request,
            'basecamp/sms.html'
        )

    else:
        return render(request, 'basecamp/sms.html', {})
```

of course, I could send sms by python shell or terminal but I wanna do this on the website because  I thought it is easy way to do (if I have to do everyday many numbers). that's why I made html page and this function. but I am not sure about the List function to collect all the numbers. I thought there is better, simple way...

Comment: to make sure, could you share your model where the number comes from?

Comment: it does not come form model.... as mentioned, it comes from the webpage... admin put the numbers manually

Comment: Or later for marketing purpose, I could get all the contact numbers from DB and put the list on the python file. that is not the issue... what I asked here is for the List function that I used... I think it takes time and a bit poor quality codes... that's why I am asking to check if there is better codes for the function I wanted